# Add empty block to Draft.js without moving selection

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

What's the best way to add an empty unstyled block, let's say last, to a Draft.js editor without changing the SelectionState?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```js
import { List } from 'immutable'
import {
  EditorState,
  ContentState,
  ContentBlock,
  genKey
} from 'draft-js'

const addEmptyBlock = (editorState) => {
  const newBlock = new ContentBlock({
    key: genKey(),
    type: 'unstyled',
    text: '',
    characterList: List()
  })

  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()
  const newBlockMap = contentState.getBlockMap().set(newBlock.key, newBlock)

  return EditorState.push(
    editorState,
    ContentState
      .createFromBlockArray(newBlockMap.toArray())
      .set('selectionBefore', contentState.getSelectionBefore())
      .set('selectionAfter', contentState.getSelectionAfter())
  )
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error while trying this


react-dom.development.js?46fb5f3:610 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at getUpdatedSelectionState (getUpdatedSelectionState.js?93c9c7b:41)
    at getDraftEditorSelectionWithNodes (getDraftEditorSelectionWithNodes.js?93c9c7b:90)
    at getDraftEditorSelection (getDraftEditorSelection.js?93bb2c4:35)
    at editOnSelect (editOnSelect.js?93bb2c4:33)
    at DraftEditor.react.js?1037aeb:218
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?46fb5f3:542)

Comment: When I use this, the block gets appended to the end.

Comment: @AdamLibuša The solution to your issue is in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/2325#issuecomment-652127067) and the explanation is in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43513374/7929984).